# Magit + gerrit - push to other branch

Tags: magit

I am using gerrit. When I want to push my commits, I use following command:

`git push origin HEAD:refs/for/master`

How can I recreate the same command using `Magit`?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

After a while I managed to have enough time to try to fix it myself.

I don't know of any "out-of-the-box" way to do this; however, you can expand magit to fit your needs.

Firstly, I wrote a function that would push to gerrit:

```
(defun magit-push-to-gerrit ()
  (interactive)
  (magit-git-command "push origin HEAD:refs/for/master" (magit-toplevel)))
```

Next, I added it to push menu:

```
(transient-append-suffix 'magit-push "p"
  '("m" "Push to gerrit" magit-push-to-gerrit))
```

These two forms are in my init file.

And that's it! Now I can use <kbd>P</kbd> <kbd>m</kbd> to push to gerrit.

**Update**:
If you want to push a specific commit and not HEAD, you can use this function (also updated with magit-git-command-topdir as referred to in the comment):

```
(defun magit-push-to-gerrit (source)
  "Push an arbitrary branch or commit to gerrit. The source is read in the minibuffer."
  (interactive
   (let ((source (magit-read-local-branch-or-commit "Push")))
     (list source)))
  (magit-git-command-topdir (concat "git push origin " source ":refs/for/master")))
```

Comment: If using an up-to-date Magit, you'll get an error from running `(magit-git-command "push origin HEAD:refs/for/master" (magit-toplevel))`. You'll want to use `(magit-git-command-topdir "git push origin HEAD:refs/for/master")` instead.

Comment: From `magit-obsolete.el`: ```* If you add additional arguments and/or actions to Magit's popups,  then you have to port that to modify the new \"transients\" instead.``` See https://github.com/magit/magit/wiki/Converting-popup-modifications-to-transient-modifications

Answer (score 4):

Use `!` to use a generic git command, then you can simple write: `push origin HEAD:refs/for/master` almost as usual.

There is also a dedicated package for `gerrit` here:
https://github.com/terranpro/magit-gerrit
I haven't used it personally however, so don't know exactly how to use it.

**EDIT**

In a recent version of `magit`, it is now possible to specify an explicit git refspec from the <kbd>r</kbd> subcommand. Thus, to push to the `gerrit` refspec, simply use:

<kbd>P</kbd> <kbd>r</kbd> "origin" <kbd>RET</kbd> "HEAD:refs/for/master"

Although, this is not really a shortcut since you have to do even more key-presses, but it *is* available out of the box.

Comment: How about some shortcuts? :)

Comment: Afraid I don't know any specific shortcuts. I did just try a regular `git push 'elsewhere'` but that prepends 'refs/heads/' to the branch destination, so that doesn't seem to work out of the box for `gerrit`.